# Activity screen orientation issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-orientation

My `Activity` only supports landscape mode by specifying

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

in manifest.

Now if my `Activity` is in foreground and some other app, which supports both orientation, gets launched and user changes orientation to portrait and hits back then my `Activity` gets crashed throwing:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
```

I guess it looks for layout resources for portrait mode briefly and layouts are only in `layout-land` so it get crashed.

E.g. I launch my app, lock the screen, rotate device to portrait mode, unlock device and I can see crash and ANR.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your layouts to the portrait directories (res/layout), in this brief moment when the system tries to render your layout then it won't crash from a resource not found exception

Comment: in fact the layout-land should be removed at all.

Comment: @donfuxx that makes sense, so in this case there should be only `layout` folder with `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to same copy of xml into `res/layout`, I think it should work, because android search all app resource according to current configuration of device(Like orientation,screensize and etc) in respective folder  ( identifiers folder) if it not find-able in that folder then android will extend their search in default folder `like res/layout, res/drawable,res/string etc.

So the reasons of crashing your app `Your layout was not present in default folder, so  whenever configuration was other then landscape it will definitly  crash.`

**Identifiers folder example.**

```
res/ layout/ main.xml ---> for portrait screen
layout-land/ main.xml ---> for landscap screen

res/ layout/ # default (portrait)
main.xml layout-land/ # landscape
main.xml layout-large/ # large (portrait)
main.xml layout-large-land/ # large landscape
main.xml

res/ drawable-xhdpi/
awesomeimage.png
drawable-hdpi/
awesomeimage.png
drawable-mdpi/
awesomeimage.png
drawable-ldpi/
```